# Fix font size for high-resolution screen

Tags: 20.04, gnome, fonts, ubuntu-gnome, qt

I have a high-resolution monitor. The font and cursor are too small for various applications. As you can see in the screenshot the font for PGAdmin is much smaller than VS code and Chrome. I thought `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0 QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.5` setting would fix this but I don't see any change. Please see my pgadmin4.desktop file below.

[image]

```
pgadmin4.desktop                                                                                                
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=pgAdmin 4
Exec=/usr/bin/env QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0 QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.5 /usr/pgadmin4/bin/pgadmin4
Icon=pgadmin4
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Development;
MimeType=text/html
Comment=Management tools for PostgreSQL
Keywords=database;db;sql;query;administration;development;
```

Answer (score 0):

As of pgAdmin4 v5.1 there is a File > Runtime menu that allows you to zoom in and out, which will affect all fonts in pgAdmin.

Comment: What if he wants to see the whole screen?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).